# Pass multiple variable values through ajax to php file, run mysql query and retrieve data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

UPDATE: I want to retrieve student full name from mysql table based on the roll number, course and semester values entered by the user.

The user types in the roll number in a text field while selects the course and semester from the select list. I want to retrieve the student name in a text field when user selects the semester from the select list after entering the roll number and selecting the course.

I am now able to retrieve student's first name in the text-box. Is there anyway I can retrieve student's middle and last name and display them in two different text boxes? Please help.

Following is the code I am using:

HTML Code:

```
    <form id="formname1" action = "" method= "post">

  <dd>
        <table>


            <tr>
                <td>Roll No.<font color = "red"><B>*</B></font></td>
                <td><input type = "text" id = "roll_number" name = "roll_number"></td>


                <td>Course:<font color = "red"><B>*</B></font></td>
                <td>
                    <select name ="course_name" id = "course">
                        <option value = "">Select</option>
                        <option value = "B.Ed">B.Ed</option>
                        <option value = "M.Ed">M.Ed</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>Semester:<font color = "red"><B>*</B></font></td>
                <td>
                    <select name ="sem" id = "sem">
                        <option value = "">Select</option>
                        <option value = "1">1</option>
                        <option value = "2">2</option>
                        <option value = "3">3</option>
                        <option value = "4">4</option>

                    </select>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Student Name:<font color = "red"><B>*</B></font></td>
                <td><input type = "text" id = "f_name" name = "s_name"></td>

                <td><input type = "text" id = "m_name" name = "m_name"></td>

                <td><input type = "text" id = "l_name" name = "l_name"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

AJX code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#sem").change(function(){

             var roll_no = $("#roll_number").val(); 
             var course = $("#course").val();
             var sem = $("#sem").val();
             $.post("retrieve_name.php",{
             r_no:roll_no,cname:course,semester:sem},

             function(data){
             $("#f_name").val((data[0].first_name));
             $("#m_name").val((data[0].middle_name));
             $("#l_name").val((data[0].last_name));
             });
             }); 
        });


</script>
```

PHP File:

```
      <?php

        $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");


$rows1 = array[]; 

$sql = "select first_name, middle_name, last_name from students s, students_in_courses sin
where s.roll_number = sin.roll_number
AND s.roll_number = '$roll' 
AND sin.course_name = '$course'
AND sin.semester = '$sem' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(!$result)
    {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";  
    }
    else
    {
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            //echo $rows[first_name];
            //echo $rows[middle_name];
            //echo $rows[last_name];
            $rows1[]= $rows;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An input can't be a content parent tag.

Change :

```
$("#s_name").html(data);
```

To :

```
$("#s_name").val(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. As suggested, changed it from .html(data) to .val(data) but still nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It turns out there was a syntax error. Now, I am able to retrieve the student first name into the text box. I also want to retrieve student's middle and last name as well in two other different text boxes. Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct script code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#sem").change(function(){

             var roll_no = $("#roll_number").val(); 
             var course = $("#course").val();
             var sem = $("#sem").val();
             $.post("test.php",{
             r_no:roll_no,cname:course,semester:sem},
             function(data){
             $("#s_name").val(data);
             });
             });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, Pramod.  It turns out there was a syntax error. Now, I am able to retrieve the student's first name into the text box. I also want to retrieve student's middle and last name as well in two other different text boxes. Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Comment: I did. Got the message stating it will be recorded but will not be displayed publicly as I am newbie to the site and need atleast 15 reputation points. Thank you, again.